# SQLCLR dynamic columns?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, sqlclr

Context SQLServer 2012, Visual Studio 2010.

I don't know if this is even possible, but I'm trying to generate the columns in the returned table dynamically.

```
List<object> columnsInfo = new List<object>();      
foreach (string entry in poodle.getKs())
{
    columnsInfo.Add( new SqlMetaData(entry, SqlDbType.Text));
}
```

poodle.getKs() has given the list of column names in an array of string.

This is where I'm getting confused. I'm trying to convert the List of object into an array of SqlMetaData and then casting that to a SqlDataRecord for assignment to the record variable.

```
SqlDataRecord record = (SqlDataRecord)columnsInfo.ToArray<SqlMetaData>();
```

The errors I'm getting on the build are

```
Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<object>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlMetaData>'
```

and

```
'System.Collections.Generic.List<object>' does not contain a definition for 'ToArray' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>)' has some invalid arguments
```

however this is the point at which my C# skills and comprehension fail. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, worked it out

```
List<SqlMetaData> columnsInfo = new List<SqlMetaData>(); 

foreach (string entry in poodle.getKs())
{
    columnsInfo.Add( new SqlMetaData(entry, SqlDbType.Text));
}

SqlDataRecord record = new SqlDataRecord(columnsInfo.ToArray<SqlMetaData>());
```

Loads up with data nicely too. Now to see if SQLServer will consume it or barf.